# Special case of the Baker Campbell Hausdorff formula: is the converse true?

Tags: combinatorics, operator-theory

For two operators $X$ and $Y$, if $[X,Y] = 0$ then $\exp(X)\exp(Y) = \exp(X+Y).$

However, I'm wondering if the converse is true:

Suppose it is given that $$e^X e^Y = e^{X + Y}.$$ Does this then imply $X$ and $Y$ commute, i.e. that $[X,Y] = 0?$

Comment: As seen below the answer is no but the following salvage is possible: if $e^{tX} e^{sY} = e^{tX+sY}$ for all real $t, s$ then $[X, Y] = 0$ (basically by taking derivatives).

Answer (score 2):

No. A counterexample with

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&2 \pi i\end{pmatrix},B=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&2 \pi i\end{pmatrix}$$

is given in lemma 5.1 of this [Msc thesis](https://www.universiteitleiden.nl/binaries/content/assets/science/mi/scripties/bachschipper.pdf).

Indeed:

$$\exp A = \exp B = \exp(A+B) = I_2 \ \implies \ \exp A * \exp B = \exp(A+B)$$

whereas $AB=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&-4 \pi^2\end{pmatrix}$

is different from $BA=\begin{pmatrix}0&2 \pi \\ 0&-4 \pi^2\end{pmatrix}.$